# Can I use CloudFlare's Proxy with an AWS Application Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-ec2, proxy, amazon-ecs, cloudflare, aws-application-load-balancer

I have created a listener on the LB (load balancer) with rules so that requests to different subdomains. I have set a CNAME for each subdomain in Cloudflare.
The problem is when I try to use Proxy feature, when I turn it off, my page works without a problem, but when i turn it on, it results in a time out.
There is a way to use Proxy feature with an LB?

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The very simple answer is yes, this is very possible to do.

The longer answer is that a timeout indicates that some change in the request by Cloudflare creates a timeout for your AWS servers. Just a couple of examples could be:

- A firewall rule that times out Cloudflare's IPs
- Servers are not respecting X-Forwarded-For header and all requests from a small group of IPs are messing with application logic

It would help to know if the requests are reaching your load balancer and furthermore if the servers behind the LB are receiving the requests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an AWS ALB managed by AWS Load Balancer Controller with Cloudflare as a proxy. It works.

I recall running into some timeout issues when figuring the setup. I believe I resolved them by getting SSL into order.

To shape up the troubleshooting approach - the difference between turning the proxy on and off is in which host your request hits first:

- With proxy off, Cloudflare is merely a DNS manager, your request hits your ALB first
- With proxy on, your request hits Cloudflare reverse proxy server first, which then forwards the request to your ALB